# Is a custom field value a ValueObject or an Entity in Domain Drive Design

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, ef-core-5.0

I am using EF Core and I have a scenario where the user can create one or more custom fields and some clients.
For each of these Clients the user must complete the custom fields values. I am confused as to where the CustomFieldValue is a ValueObject or an entity. And where it fits into my design? In Client Entity or CustomField Entity.
Note that some Custom Fields are not required to be completed so they might not have a value.

```
public class CustomField : Entity<long>
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public bool IsRequired { get; private set; }
    
    protected CustomField()
    {
    }

    public CustomField(long id, string name, bool isRequired)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        IsRequired = isRequired;
    }
}

public class CustomFieldValue
{    
    public string Text { get; private set; }       
}

public class Client : Entity<long>
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    //....Some other properties of client
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd model it like this:

```
public class CustomField : Entity<long>
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public bool IsRequired { get; private set; }
    
    protected CustomField()
    {
    }

    public CustomField(long id, string name, bool isRequired)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        IsRequired = isRequired;
    }
}

public class CustomFieldValue
{    
    public long Id {get; private set;}
    public string Text { get; private set; } 
      
    public CustomField Field {get; private set;}
}

public class Client : Entity<long>
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    IEnumerable<CustomFieldValue> CustomFieldValues {get; private set;}
    //....Some other properties of client
}
```

Is `CustomFieldValue` an entity?
Value objects can be interchangeable, one could be replaced by another with the same content. If we look at them isolated from what client they belong to, they will effectively look like a pair "Field Id, Value" which are interchangeable which makes them a value object.

Comment: Based on your model above a Client does not have a CustomFieldValue set which is my main requirement. Maybe my initial description was not clear enough and it confused you. Custom fields are created throughout the system (via system settings) and once created they are all available to any new or existing clients.

Comment: I edited my response. Try this model. It may fit or it may not, depends on how you want to use it.

Comment: so if they are extended properties of a client that means they are value objects not entities